# Both the apks generated by intellij are 'debug' builds

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, intellij-13

I am using gradle build for my android project.I am building the project in Intellij.However when I run the application both the apks generated are 'debug' build.Shouldn't ideally one be a 'release' build or I am missiong something.
I have provided the signing configuration provided for 'release' build.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out.When we choose the debug build in Intellij,two apks are generated namely---
i)Aligned debug apk
ii)Unaligned debug apk

Unaligned debug apk is generated to speed up the process of generating the aligned debug apk.You can also run the debug build process from command line(Ubuntu) using *./gradlew assemleDebug --info* command.

When we choose the release build in Intellij,one release apk is generated.You can also run the release build process using the command *./gradlew assembleRelease --info*.